# Is a horizontal for possible with Grommet?

Tags: forms, reactjs, grommet

I would like to create a horizontal or inline form with the Grommet React library. I am loving it but either I am missing something, or some simple things like inline forms are not possible with it. Can anyone shed any light on how to achieve the following AirBNB form style with Grommet?

[image]

Note: I did try using columns but as soon as the Form element is added, it gets blocky and becomes vertical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set a box inside the form with `direction='row'` then inside it the FormFields.

[image]

Here a [codepen](http://codepen.io/MarcoMedrano/pen/pPwozN?editors=1010) (: